# jqgrid search window doesn't appear

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have set up my jqGrid as below:

```
$(function () {
$('#POesGrid').jqGrid({
    caption: '',
    colNames: ['POID', 'PO Number', 'Revision', 'Date Created', 'Date PO Approved', 'Supplier',
        'Status', 'Ship To', 'Payment', '', '', ''],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'POID', hidden: true, key: true },
        { name: 'PONumber', index: 'PONumber', search:true, searchtype:'number' },
        { name: 'PORevision', index: 'PORevision', search: true },
        { name: 'DateOfCreated', index: 'DateOfCreated', search: true },
        { name: 'DateOfApproved', index: 'DateOfApproved', search: true },
        { name: 'AdrBookSuplierPO', index: 'AdrBookSuplierPO.LastName', search: true },
        { name: 'StatusPO', index: 'StatusPO.StatusTitle', search: true },
        { name: 'ShipTo', index: 'ShipTo.LastName', search: true },
        { name: 'Payment', sortable: false },
        { name: 'EditAction', sortable: false, classes: 'edit', width:25 },
        { name: 'DetailAction', sortable: false, classes: 'view', width: 25 },
        { name: 'DeleteAction', sortable: false, classes: 'delete', width: 25 },
    ],
    pager: '#POesGridPager',
    rowNum: paramFromView.PageSize,
    rowList: [10, 50, 100],
    datatype: 'json',
    height: '100%',
    sortname: 'PONumber',
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    mtype: 'GET',
    jsonReader: {
        root: "rows",
        page: "page",
        total: "total",
        records: "records",
        repeatitems: false,
        userdata: "userdata"
    },
    url: paramFromView.Url
}).navGrid('#POesGridPager', { del: false, add: false, edit: false},
{},
{},
{},
{ multipleSearch: true });
});
```

When I click on the search button the full page get disabled (which normally happens when the search screen appears), but the search screen doesn't appear.

Can you please let me know what I am missing here?

My JQGrid version is 4.6.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the reason, i had included some files which are not required.
I had downloaded the package via nuget, and added some files which are downloaded via jqgrid site. (These additional files are not required for the nuget package). Removed them and it works file a charm.

Yes, I'm kicking myself!